# What does it mean to "embedding of a sequence into an sequence"? Can you show it with real-world examples?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please refer to the screenshot below from a research article:

[Screenshot showing embedding of sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2XNk.png).

What is the meaning of embedding here, could you point out specific resources/sources to learn more about this. This concept is crucial for understanding the relevant concepts (i.e., interleaving of two or more sequences) in the research paper. An explanation with suitable example(s) would be highly appreciated.

I have tried to search this concept online, but have not been able to figure out. While the following definition defines the term embedding, it is not making sense in the context (see the screenshot below).

Comment: Sequence $A$ is embedded in sequence $B$ iff $A$ is a subsequence of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Don't they just mean something like embedding of $a=(1,2,3,4)$ in the sequence $b=(0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,4,0,\ldots)$?

In other words, you have some strictly increasing re-mapping of indices $emb$ such that $b_{emb(n)}=a_n$ for all $n$ in the domain of $a$? In the example above, $emb=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2&3\\3&6&10&11\end{pmatrix}$.